# Error in Italian localization for datepicker

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Well, this is very funny :)

I have a datepicker localized in Italian. It works correctly, except that, apparently, the abbreviation for Wednesday was translated as it were a personal pronoun, since *noi* is the Italian translation for *we*.

> [image: screenshot from datepicker, illustrating the error in translation]

The abbreviation for Wednesday is correctly set in *core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-it.js*, but this file is not inserted in the HTML, so I suppose the translation is taken somewhere else.

In my libraries dependencies I have the following code.

```
dependencies:
  - core/jquery
  - core/jquery.once
  - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
  - core/drupal.locale.datepicker
```

Without the last line, the date picker is in English.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess the problem is in `core/modules/locale/locale.datepicker.js` at line 20, where `dayNamesMin[3]` is set to `Drupal.t('We')`: it doesn't seem like a good idea, does it? Is it reasonable to report it as a bug in core?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download [Italian initialisation jQuery UI js file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-it.js) and attached to your concerned page in your module or theme.

Comment: But that is a jQuery UI file not adapted to the Drupal environment, isn't it? If I compare it to `core/modules/locale/locale.datepicker.js`, which is where `Drupal.t('We')` occurs, I can see that the code is not run in a behavior. I would anyway be surprised that such a basic configuration would require the download of a file from another project... even since the translation _works_, the problem is that translating "We" is not a good idea!

Comment: Here is a code snnipet from `date_popup_load` to load english version of ui datepicker  `if (module_exists('jquery_ui')) {
    jquery_ui_add('ui.datepicker');

    // Add i18n support
    global $language;
    if ($language->language != 'en') {
        drupal_add_js (JQUERY_UI_PATH.'/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-'.($language->language).'.js');
    }
  }` try to implement the same in `hook_library_info_build` to load ui datepicker-it .

Comment: [hook_library_info_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_build/8.6.x)

Comment: But why should I reimplement something that is present and working? The only problem is that it does incorrectly translate the abbreviation for Wednesday. If this won't get corrected, I think I'll simply have to override `core/modules/locale/locale.datepicker.js`...

Comment: Try to add `core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/ui/i18n/datepicker.it.js`  to script section in `YourTheme.libraries.yml` `script:
  js:
  Path_to_datepicker/i18n/datepicker.it.js`, and see if the script loaded if is the case check if the translation in this file is correct.

Comment: @FrancescoMarchetti-Stasi: come hai risolto?

Comment: @PonzioPilato, unfortunately I _didn't_ solve it. I simply changed the translation of "We" to "Me", it works as long as I don't have a "We" in the interface...